# How do I read this private key as an ECPrivateKey in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, private-key, pem

I have the following private key, and am attempting to read it as an instance of ECPrivateKey using BouncyCaste with the following code. However, I'm getting a null pointer exception:

Key:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQgtqnvswtIdNxKy07B
D3Y9vvlpwvSDqWCvyWmWTNea2ImgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAATa0LtPPOI+De/u
RY1vSxR7gFGSoyjaDZyif/sWujLZWEj6Rc2IEl62VfWQD3GeYCEEKP9qzpOGyO+b
HWR98kNd
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Parsing code:

```
private PrivateKey readPemAsPrivateKey(final String pem) throws IOException {
    final PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(pem));
    final Object parsedPem = pemParser.readObject();
    if (!(parsedPem instanceof PEMKeyPair)) {
        throw new IOException("Attempted to parse PEM string as a keypair, but it's actually a " + parsedPem.getClass());
    }

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    final JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");

    return converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) parsedPem).getPrivate();
}
```

The exception:

```
! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
! ... 29 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: unable to convert key pair: null
! at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter.getKeyPair(Unknown Source) ~
```

Does anyone know how I can read this key as an ECPrivateKey object?

Note:

When I run the following openssl command, it spits the key out in a format that Bouncycastle *does* accept. Unfortunately, in production I don't have the option to pre-process the key--I have to work with the key as-is and process it in code.

```
$ openssl ec -inform PKCS8 -in T5TK5598S7.p8 
read EC key
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIGaopmcUKDBihelMJbKUyRmaR6F3Eo90EZaqZJ3/mBr0oAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEnYaxPG+o57xM5o/M5QNn0ocwlw12ZNVWFEo9tKDQ7Jz5Gz/0eMcP
mEhm5msFFpWgrY0/T92MfwByuaLws/rM3w==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: The body of the original key does not correspond to a key in SEC1 format, but in PKCS#8 format. However, header and footer are wrong, which can be corrected by removing `EC` from both. `PEMParser#readObject()` then returns a `PrivateKeyInfo` object that can be imported with `JcaPEMKeyConverter#getPrivateKey()`.

Comment: @Topaco That did the trick. Thank you! If you want to post this as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it